# Crear un array en un JSON con informacion de una base de datos Delphi

Tags: array, json, base-de-datos, while, delphi

tengo un JSON con la siguiente estructura:

```
{"Numbers":[["1","a"],["2","b"]]}
```

La idea es introducirle un numero, y un string, en ese mismo formato, hasta ahora, hago eso de la siguiente manera:

```
 Var
MainJSON  : TJSONObject;
JSONArray, JSONNumeros, JSONNumeros2 : TJSONArray;
Filename : String;
begin
// ----------------- Escribir el JSON ------
try
 MainJson := TJSONObject.Create;
 try
  JSONArray := TJSONArray.Create;
  JSONNumeros := TJSONArray.Create;
  MainJSON.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('Numbers', JSONArray));

  JSONNumeros.add('1');
  JSONNumeros.add('a');
  JSONArray.Add(JSONNumeros);

  JSONNumeros2.add('2');
  JSONNumeros2.add('b');
  JSONArray.Add(JSONNumeros2);


  Filename:= (ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'\Data.Json');
  TFile.WriteAllText(Filename , MainJson.ToJSON, TEncoding.UTF8);
 finally
 MainJSON.Free;
 end;

 except
  on E: Exception do
  Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
end;
end;
```

Pero, necesito agregar mas datos a la cadena, y no quiero agregar otra variable al TJSONArray como por ejemplo "JSONNumeros3" como hago para agregar mas datos a la cadena en tiempo de ejecucion?, la idea es agregarlo desde la informacion obtenida desde una base de datos, algo como:

```
Var
MainJSON  : TJSONObject;
JSONArray, JSONNumeros, JSONNumeros2 : TJSONArray;
Filename : String;
begin
// ----------------- Escribir el JSON------
try
 MainJson := TJSONObject.Create;
 try
  JSONArray := TJSONArray.Create;
  JSONNumeros := TJSONArray.Create;
  MainJSON.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('Numbers', JSONArray));

  While not Query.eof do
   Begin
   JSONNumeros.add(Query.FieldByName('Numero').asstring);
   JSONNumeros.add(Query.FieldByName('Texto').asstring);
   JSONArray.Add(JSONNumeros);
   Next;
   end;


  Filename:= (ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'\Data.Json');
  TFile.WriteAllText(Filename , MainJson.ToJSON, TEncoding.UTF8);
 finally
 MainJSON.Free;
 end;

 except
  on E: Exception do
  Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
end;
end;
```

Alguna idea? Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que lo que necesitas, se podría conseguir con un blucle (similar al que has puesto tú en el segundo código) si los campos del `query` son fijos, o con 2 bucles si quieres hacerlo con TODOS los campos del `query`.

Suponiendo que tu `query` sea similar a este (campos y registros cambiarán):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La primera opción es que sólo quieras exportar algunos campos. En ese caso, el código podría ser como este:

```
Var
  MainJSON  : TJSONObject;
  JSONArray, JSONNumeros: TJSONArray;
  Filename : String;
begin
  // ----------------- Escribir el JSON------
  try
    MainJson := TJSONObject.Create;
    JSONArray := TJSONArray.Create;
    MainJSON.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('Numbers', JSONArray));
    // recorrer el query/Dataset7Table
    cdsDatos.First;
    While not cdsDatos.eof do Begin
      JSONNumeros := TJSONArray.Create;
      // Exportar sólo los campos necesarios
      JSONNumeros.add(cdsDatos.FieldByName('Codigo').asstring);
      JSONNumeros.add(cdsDatos.FieldByName('Nombre').asstring);
      JSONNumeros.add(cdsDatos.FieldByName('DNI').asstring);
      // Añadir ese registro al array general
      JSONArray.Add(JSONNumeros);
      // Siguiente registro
      cdsDatos.Next;
    end;
    // Output (fichero o pantalla)
    Filename:= (ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'\Data.Json');
    TFile.WriteAllText(Filename , MainJson.ToJSON, TEncoding.UTF8);
    Memo1.Lines.Text := MainJson.ToString;
  finally
    // MainJSON.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Si por lo que sea, los campos no son fijos, sino que quieres exportar todos, se podría simplificar el código con un segundo bucle que recorriera todos los campos del `Dataset`, de forma que el código podría ser similar a este:

```
Var
  MainJSON  : TJSONObject;
  JSONArray, JSONNumeros: TJSONArray;
  Filename : String;
begin
  try
    MainJson := TJSONObject.Create;
    JSONArray := TJSONArray.Create;
    MainJSON.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('Numbers', JSONArray));
    // Colocarse en el proimer registro
    cdsDatos.First;
    // recorrer el query/Dataset
    While not cdsDatos.eof do Begin
      JSONNumeros := TJSONArray.Create;
      // recorrer todos los campos del Dataset/Query
      for var I:integer := 0 to (cdsDatos.FieldCount - 1) do
        JSONNumeros.add(cdsDatos.Fields[i].asstring);  // valor del campo
      // Añadir ese registro
      JSONArray.Add(JSONNumeros);
      // siguiente registro
      cdsDatos.Next;
    end;
    // output a fichero o pantalla
    Filename:= (ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'\Data.Json');
    TFile.WriteAllText(Filename , MainJson.ToJSON, TEncoding.UTF8);
    Memo1.Lines.Text := MainJson.ToString;
    ...
end;
```

Si no son todos los campos de la `query/dataset`, pero hay bastantes, en lugar de repetir un código como este para todos los campos:

```
  // Exportar sólo los campos necesarios
  JSONNumeros.add(cdsDatos.FieldByName('Codigo').asstring);
  JSONNumeros.add(cdsDatos.FieldByName('Nombre').asstring);
  JSONNumeros.add(cdsDatos.FieldByName('DNI').asstring);
  ...
```

Sería más efectivo definir un `Array` con los campos a exportar; Algo como esto:

```
const
  arrayFields: TArray<string> = ['Codigo', 'Nombre', 'DNI', 'Dirección'];
```

Y esas líneas repetitivas se convertirían en un buble que recorra los valores del array.

Con este código y los datos del ejemplo inicial la salida será similar a esta:

```
{
    "Numbers": [
        [
            "1",
            "Juan",
            "11111111h",
            "c/ almendros 123"
        ],
        [
            "2",
            "Pepe",
            "22222222E",
            "c/ Naranjos 23"
        ],
        [
            "3",
            "María",
            "33333333R",
            "c/ Judía 34"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar tantos registros como quieras al arreglo sin utilizar más variables.

Si tus datos vienen de un DataSet, podrías agregarlos todos en un ciclo utilizando una única variable de tipo `TJsonArray`. Partiendo de tu código, podrías obtenerlo con:

```
var
  MainJSON: TJSONObject;
  Numbers, Number: TJsonArray;
  FileName: string;
begin
  MainJSON := TJSONObject.Create;
  try
    Numbers := TJSONArray.Create;
    MainJSON.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('Numbers', Numbers));
    Query.First;
    while not Query.Eof do
    begin
      Number := TJSONArray.Create;
      Number.Add(Query.FieldByName('Numero').AsString);
      Number.Add(Query.FieldByName('Texto').AsString);
      Numbers.Add(Number);
      Query.Next;
    end;
    FileName := 'c:\test\json\datos.json';
    TFile.WriteAllText(FileName, MainJSON.ToJSON, TEncoding.UTF8);
  finally
    MainJSON.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Si observas detenidamente, en cada iteración del ciclo creo una nueva instancia de `TJSONArray`, asignándola a la misma variable `Number`. En esta nueva instancia agrego los valores que vienen del dataset y finalmente agrego este arreglo a la variable `Numbers`.

He cambiado los nombres de las variables, ya que creo que aportan una mayor claridad al código, pero esto es algo arbitrario y podrías seguir utilizando los nombres que ya traías.

El resultado que obtengo, con un conjunto de datos de prueba, es el siguiente:

```
{"Numbers":[["1","a"],["2","b"],["3","c"],["4","d"],["5","e"],["6","f"],["7","g"],["8","h"],["9","i"],["10","j"],["11","k"]]}
```